# What should go in a post-mortem debug information snap-shot for a Java program?

Tags: java, postmortem-debugging

We have a situation where we would like to be able to create a zip file containing as much information as possible about a currently running Java program (which may be on its way down) to allow for post-mortem forensic analysis.  We currently deploy to Java 5 but Java 6 features are interesting too.

So far I've thought of:

- A programmatically generated thread dump. This appears to work better in Java 6.
- The logged log events for the last X minutes.  We currently use logback or java.util.logging.
- Some serialized objects.
- External environment - all system properties.

What else would be useful of JVM information?

Would it be possible in a generic way to walk the call stacks and see the arguments?  (or does this require JVMTI or equivalent).  It is a IBM JVM so we cannot use jvisualvm and the Attach API.

Comment: FYI: You can use VisualVM with explicit JXM connection. See for example http://3rdstage.blogspot.com/2010/12/using-visualvm-with-ibm-jdk.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could go all the way and capture a full heap dump?  I realize you are on an IBM JVM, but [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21242497) seems to indicate there is a way.